# Small modification to a SQL query to show only the unique and non empty recprds

Tags: php, sql

I need to extract all the emails from my database. However there are many records that are blank but are displayed through the sql I wrote. How can I show all the unique and not empty records?

Thank you

```
SELECT comment_author_email
FROM  `wp_comments`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment_author_email
FROM  `wp_comments`
WHERE comment_author_email != ''
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    SELECT DISTINCT comment_author_email
    FROM  `wp_comments` 
    where comment_author_email IS NOT NULL AND comment_author_email != '';
```

Answer (score 1):

check this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment_author_email FROM `wp_comments` 
WHERE comment_author_email IS NOT NULL AND comment_author_email <> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the group by function instead of the distinct.  This allows you to include aggregate functions in your query that provide additional information.

```
SELECT comment_author_email, count(1)
FROM  `wp_comments`
WHERE comment_author_email != ''
GROUP BY comment_author_email
```

This will return one row per unique comment_author_email value and the number of times it occurs.